# VSCode workspace settings inheriting from default settings not user settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have updated my user settings to change font in VS Code, but these never seem to take effect.

Say, I open a new folder in VS Code, the settings are set to default. When I look at the settings I can see that the Workspace settings are the default. There is no .vscode folder in the folder, I do not have any default settings in the .vscode folder in my profile root folder either.

Am I missing something?

See the screenshots below.

[image: user setting]

[image: workspace setting]

I would have assumed that that workspace setting would be the same as the one in User, but it isn't. Also, the font is installed and if I copy-paste the value from User to Workspace, the changes take effect. I also don't understand what the ***(Modified in: User)*** means.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Workspace settings are always default, unless you change them. Only then VS Code will create a _.vscode_ folder in your project root. User settings are global.
You want to change your global font setting? Did you do that via the UI? Is your font installed? Fonts with spaces in their name need to be added like this `'Fira Code', Menlo, Monaco, monospace`

Comment: The font is installed and working. I ideally want my new workspace to get the font from my user setting, which overrides the default setting. It's not doing that.  Sorry, if that was not clear, I have edited the question to try and be more explicit.

Comment: Workspace settings always start with a clean slate, so to speak, for every workspace. That is normal. The "Modified in: User" is just a hint to let you know which default settings have been modified. Settings modified in the User tab should be applied to every workspace, unless you created specific workspace settings. Your Fira Code font should work everywhere. Apparently you no longer need the quotes also. If you want to create Workspace settings with your User settings as the starting point, it's probably best to just copy the JSON over and then make whatever other changes.

Comment: Thanks @hotpink, I think I misunderstood what Workspace settings were. All good now.

Comment: @ilias, just for the closure sake, when you get a chance please provide the answer and close the loop. That will help fellow SOers who might stumble up on this in future

Answer (score 1):

Workspace settings and user settings are defined separately.

[From the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settings):

> Workspace settings are specific to a project and can be shared across developers on a project. Workspace settings override user settings.

The workspace settings tab doesn't show the value from user settings if there is such a user-settings value and no value has been set to override it in the workspace settings. It just shows the default value of the setting in such cases. "*(Modified in: User)*" means that the setting has been modified in the user settings "layer".